# WSO2 API Manager APIStoreHostObject Error from Registry API

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I rebuilt my host machine which has WSO2 and used the existing wso2 database. So its a new instance which is newly configured ;but pointing to the existing database.When i invoke the existing API's , i am getting the below exception. Its a WSO2 idenity server and api manager together.

```
     [2017-05-14 05:25:28,230] ERROR - APIStoreHostObject Error from Registry API while getting get API Information on myapp
    org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Failed to get API from : /apimgt/applicationdata/provider/admin/myapp/v1/api
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.handleException(AbstractAPIManager.java:1063)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.getAPI(AbstractAPIManager.java:373)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject.jsFunction_getAPI(APIStoreHostObject.java:1918)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

aused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource does not exist at path /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/admin/myapp/v1/api
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.get(MountHandler.java:449)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.get(HandlerManager.java:2444)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.UserDefinedHandlerManager.get(UserDefinedHandlerManager.java:200)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.get(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:914)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.get(EmbeddedRegistry.java:512)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.getGhostResourceFromCache(CacheBackedRegistry.java:225)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.get(CacheBackedRegistry.java:198)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getInternal(UserRegistry.java:617)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$400(UserRegistry.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$5.run(UserRegistry.java:597)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$5.run(UserRegistry.java:594)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.get(UserRegistry.java:594)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.getAPI(AbstractAPIManager.java:352)
```

Comment: Are you sure registry mounting configurations are correct?

Comment: Where to check it?

Comment: `master-datasources.xml` and `registry.xml`

Comment: https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Pre-Packaged+Identity+Server+5.2.0+with+API+Manager+2.0.0
This documentation has a reference to <cacheId>root@jdbc:mysql://10.20.30.42:3306/registrydb</cacheId>
in the Create the registry mounts portion
Which is this IP? Also is it registrydb?

Comment: Yes it is registry db jdbc url.

Comment: is it regdb? ideally the document should be mentioning localhost instead of this ip.